# Constructing a coreflection functor from its components

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a coreflective subcategory of $\mathbf{B}$ and for all $B$, $A_B\xrightarrow{c_B}B$ an $\mathbf{A}$-coreflection.

This is $\forall$ $\mathbf{B}$-objects $B$. I claim that there exists a unique functor $C:\mathbf{B}\to\mathbf{A}$ s.t. $C(B)=A_B$ $\forall$ $\mathbf{B}$-objects $B$, and for each $\mathbf{B}$-morphism $f:B\to B'$, the diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C(B) @>{c_B}>> B\\
@V{C(f)}VV @V{f}VV \\
C(B') @>{c_{B'}}>> B'
\end{CD}
$$

commutes. It's easy to see why $C$ is uniquely defined on objects, but I'm struggling to prove that it is uniquely defined on $\mathbf{B}$-morphisms, and that it is a functor.

Definitions: Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a subcategory for $\mathbf{B}$, and let $B$ be a $\mathbf{B}$-object. Then an $\mathbf{A}$-coreflection for $B$ is a $\mathbf{B}$-morphism $A\xrightarrow{c}B$ from an $\mathbf{A}$-object $A$ to $B$ with the following universal property:

for any $\mathbf{B}$-morphism $A'\xrightarrow{F}B$ for some $\mathbf{A}$-object $A'$ to $B$, there exists a unique $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $f':A'\to A$ s.t. $f=c\circ f'$.

$\mathbf{A}$ is considered to be a coreflective subcategory of $\mathbf{B}$ when, for each $\mathbf{B}$-object $B$, there exists some $\mathbf{A}$-coreflection for $B$.

Comment: In your title, you're saying some morphisms are coreflections. What does that mean? Do you mean a family of them, i.e., a functor? What text are you reading. Definitely consider rewriting you question.

Comment: Hopefully it should be more clear now. I added some definitions at the bottom.

Comment: By the way, the textbook I'm using is Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats – by Adámek, Herrlich, and Strecker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C(f)$ is just the factorization of $f\circ c_B$ through $c_{B'}$ required by the definition of the coreflection arrow. Functoriality then follows using uniqueness: the identity of $A_B$ makes the square for $c(\mathrm{id}_B)$ commute, and similarly for a composition of $c(f)$ with $c(g)$.

Answer (score 1):

Thank-you for giving me the definitions!
This is my first time with the concept of coreflective subcategories!
Below is my answer to your problem; after rephrasing the definitions
a bit to introduce some handy-dandy notation!

Hope it help!

## Set up

Say a subcategory  of , is coreflective iff
we have operations

```
Core : Obj  → Obj 
[_]  : Obj  → Mor
```

that interact by the typing rule: for an -object B,

```
“[]-type”  [ B ] : Core B ⟶ B
```

and we have a third operation

```
⟨_⟩   : Mor  → Mor
```

that interacts with the previous two by the axiom:
for any -morphism f and -morphism g, we have

```
“⟨⟩-char” ⟨ f ⟩ = g ≡ f = [ Tgt f ] ∘ g
```

Interestingly, taking g ≔ ⟨ f ⟩ in this characterisation yields the
property mentioned in the OP's universal property:

```
“[]-⟨⟩-char”  f = [ Tgt f ] ∘ ⟨ f ⟩
```

Using this equality, we can then derive

```
“⟨⟩-type”   ⟨ f ⟩ : Src f ⟶ Core (Tgt f)
```

## Making Core into a functor

We'd like to extend Core to be defined on arrows as well;
let this extension be named .

Then, we need

```
 :  ⟶ 
 B = Core B
 (f : X ⟶ B) : Core X ⟶ Core B
```

For the definition on arrows, we have that

```
⟨ f ⟩ : X ⟶ Core B , [ X ] : Core X ⟶ X
```

thus one candidate is

```
 f ≔ ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ [ Src f ]
```

Let's try it out and see if it works!

## functorial

### preserves composition

```
   f ∘  g
={ definition of  }
  ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ [ Src f ] ∘ ⟨ g ⟩ ∘ [ Src g ]
={ f ∘ g is well defined iff Src f = Tgt g }
  ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ [ Tgt g ] ∘ ⟨ g ⟩ ∘ [ Src g ]
={ []-⟨⟩-char }
  ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ g ∘ [ Src g ]
={ can continue if ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ g = ⟨ f ∘ g ⟩ , to be proved later }
  ⟨ f ∘ g ⟩ ∘ [ Src g ]
={ Src (f ∘ g) = Src g }
  ⟨ f ∘ g ⟩ ∘ [ Src (f ∘ g) ]
={ definition of  }
   (f ∘ g)
```

It remains to show the claim,

```
   ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ g = ⟨ f ∘ g ⟩
≡{ ⟨⟩-char }
   f ∘ g = [ Tgt (f ∘ g) ] ∘ ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ g
≡{ Tgt (f ∘ g) = Tgt f }
   f ∘ g = [ Tgt f ] ∘ ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ g
≡{ []-⟨⟩-char }
   f ∘ g = f ∘ g
≡{ reflexitivity of equality }
   true
```

such a fusion of bracketing ⟨⟩ and composition may well be termed
`⟨⟩-∘-fusion'.

### preserves identity

```
    Idₓ
={ definition of  }
   ⟨ Idₓ ⟩ ∘ [ X ]
={ ⟨⟩-∘-fusion }
   ⟨ Idₓ ∘ [ X ] ⟩
={ identity is unit of composition }
   ⟨[ X ]⟩
={ claim }
   Id (Core X)
={ definition of  }
   Id ( X)
```

It remains to prove the claim, suppressing arguments to Id,

```
  ⟨[ X ]⟩ = Id
≡{ ⟨⟩-char }
  [ X ] = [ Tgt ([ X ]) ] ∘ Id
≡{ []-typing }
  [ X ] = [ X ] ∘ Id
≡{ unit of composition and reflexitivty of equality }
  true
```

## The desired property

```
(*)  ∀ f : X ⟶ Y    •     f ∘ [ X ] = [ Y ] ∘  f
```

### satisfies property (*)

```
  [ Tgt f ] ∘  f
={ definition of  }
  [ Tgt f ] ∘ ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ [ Src f ]
={ []-⟨⟩-char }
  f ∘ [ Src f ]
```

### is the only functor satisfying (*)

Suppose a given functor C' satisfies (*) then it must be the same as :

```
   f
={ definition of  }
  ⟨ f ⟩ ∘ [ Src f ]
={ unit of composition and ⟨⟩-∘-fusion }
  ⟨ Id (Tgt f) ⟩ ∘ f ∘ [ Src f ]
={ assumption of C' satisfying (*) }  
  ⟨ Id (Tgt f) ⟩ ∘ [ Tgt f ] ∘ C' f
={ definition of  --suppressing implicit argument to Id }
   Id ∘ C' f
={  functor }
  Id ∘ C' f
={ unit of composition }   
  C' f
```

## Conclusion

I don't really know what a coreflection is; I have no intuitive understanding of it :-( Let me know if you, the reader, do!

However, I introduced some notations with rules and massaged the symbols here and there to prove the result and that's a fun game :-)

## Addendum

@[Kevin](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1831097/80406), in another answer here, says
“$C(f)$  is just the factorization of $f ∘ c_B$ through $c_B′$ required by the definition of the coreflection arrow.” In my notation, he's saying  `f = ⟨ f ∘ [ Src f ] ⟩`
which is fact identical to the definition of  we found above due to ⟨⟩-∘-fusion!

I must admit that his presentation seems more professional and succinct than my own but that's to be expected
since I've just learned a bit about this concept today.

Comment: A coreflection (and a coreflective subcategory) is the dual concept of a reflection (and a reflective subcategory). A subcategory is coreflective if and only if it's dual is a reflective subcategory of the dual of the larger category (the result for reflections and coreflections is analogous).